# Haskell: Loading a file with a definition fails, while doing it interactively in GHCi works well. Why?

Tags: haskell, load, interactive, ghci, ambiguous

I am using GHCi 8.10.2 on Win 10.
I have a source file named src\LoadAndInteractiveDiffer.hs containing only:

```
module LoadAndInteractiveDiffer where

testNothingIsNothing = Nothing == Nothing
```

When loading it into GHCi, I get:

```
Prelude> :l src/LoadAndInteractiveDiffer.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling LoadAndInteractiveDiffer ( src\LoadAndInteractiveDiffer.hs, interpreted )

src\LoadAndInteractiveDiffer.hs:3:24: error:
    * Ambiguous type variable `a0' arising from a use of `=='
      prevents the constraint `(Eq a0)' from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `a0' should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Eq Ordering -- Defined in `GHC.Classes'
        instance Eq Integer
          -- Defined in `integer-gmp-1.0.3.0:GHC.Integer.Type'
        instance Eq a => Eq (Maybe a) -- Defined in `GHC.Maybe'
        ...plus 22 others
        ...plus six instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    * In the expression: Nothing == Nothing
      In an equation for `testNothingIsNothing':
          testNothingIsNothing = Nothing == Nothing
  |
3 | testNothingIsNothing = Nothing == Nothing
  |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

However, when I do the same thing interactively, the behavior is as expected:

```
-- Works fine:
Prelude> testNothingIsNothing = Nothing == Nothing
Prelude>

-- Works fine:
Prelude> testNothingIsNothing
True
```

What have I missed here?

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the type `a` of `Maybe a`. In `ghci` it makes a guess and will do type defaulting.

Here we can for example work with `Integer`, since `Integer` is a member of the `Eq` typeclass:

```
testNothingIsNothing = Nothing == (Nothing :: Maybe Integer)
```

GHCi has [*extended defaulting rules* [haskell-report]](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules). Since here there is only a type constraint `Eq` on `a`, it will normally work with `Maybe ()`. For more information about type defaulting, you can reed [this article named "*Type defaulting in Haskell*" of *Kwang's  Haskell blog*](https://kseo.github.io/posts/2017-01-04-type-defaulting-in-haskell.html).

You can enable the extended type defaulting for a file with a language pragma:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExtendedDefaultRules #-}

testNothingIsNothing = Nothing == Nothing
```

In fact you can enable it for some files, and for others, you do not. For the interactive part of ghci, this is enabled.

Comment: Thanks for an interesting input, it maybe answers (part of?) my question; The loading takes part in the GHCi as does also the manually typing in. All the same, it behaves differently. In other words, GHCi is involved in both cases, nonetheless the behavior is different.

Comment: @ØyvindRoth: it will load the file *without* the extended type defaulting, but the items written during the interactive session are *with* the extended defaulting. In fact you can enable the extension with the `{-# LANGUAGE ExtendedDefaultRules #-}` pragma so for some files you work with this extension, and for others you don't.

Answer (score 2):

`Nothing` has type `Maybe a`. `a` must be filled in to use the type, but there is nothing in your program to let GHc infer what the `a` might be, hence the error.

When GHCi encounters an ambiguous type variable at the prompt, it uses [Defaulting rules](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#type-defaulting-in-ghci) to resolve them, So `Nothing` is defaulted to `Maybe ()`. However, when it loads a module from a file, the normal GHC convention is followed (unless the extension `ExtendedDefaultRules` is enabled, in which case GHCi-style defaulting is always enabled).

Comment: Thanks for an interesting input, but it does not actually answer my question. Why the difference between loading and manually typing in?

Comment: @ØyvindRoth Briefly put, GHC(i) has slightly different defaults for code in .hs files and code written at the GHCi prompt. At the prompt, GHCi uses more heuristics to guess what the user means, so to be a bit less pedantic on code which is meant to be thrown away soon. In .hs files, instead, GHC requires more pedantry requiring the user to be non-ambiguous. E.g. `show []` could evaluate to `"[]"` or to `"\"\""`, depending on whether `[]` is an empty list of non-chars, or one of chars (empty string). GHCi picks the former at the prompt, even if it's ambiguous. (I'm not a huge fan of this, BTW)