# Variant 2: Haskell: Loading a file with a definition fails, while doing it interactively in GHCi works well. Why?

Tags: haskell, load, interactive, ghci, ambiguous

I thought the distilled problem here: [Haskell: Loading a file with a definition fails, while doing it interactively in GHCi works well. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68713776/haskell-loading-a-file-with-a-definition-fails-while-doing-it-interactively-in) would solve the *actual* problem which is a solution to Haskell Programming from first principles Chap 15.10. But sorry, no.

I am using GHCi 8.10.2 on Win 10. I have a source file named src\LoadAndInteractiveDiffer2.hs containing:

```
module LoadAndInteractiveDiffer2 where

data Optional a =
      Nada
    | Only a
    deriving (Show)

instance Eq a => Eq (Optional a) where
    (==) (Only x) (Only y) = x == y
    (==)  Nada     Nada    = True
    (==)  _        _       = False    

instance (Eq a, Semigroup a) => Semigroup (Optional a) where
    (<>)  Nada     Nada    = Nada
    (<>) (Only x)  Nada    = Only x
    (<>)  Nada    (Only y) = Only y
    (<>) (Only x) (Only y) = Only (x <> y)

testNadaNada = Nada <> Nada == Nada
```

When loading it into GHCi, I get:

```
Prelude> :l src/LoadAndInteractiveDiffer2.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling LoadAndInteractiveDiffer2 ( src\LoadAndInteractiveDiffer2.hs, interpreted )

src\LoadAndInteractiveDiffer2.hs:19:16: error:
    * Ambiguous type variable `a0' arising from a use of `<>'
      prevents the constraint `(Semigroup a0)' from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `a0' should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Semigroup a => Semigroup (IO a) -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
        instance Semigroup Ordering -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
        instance (Eq a, Semigroup a) => Semigroup (Optional a)
          -- Defined at src\LoadAndInteractiveDiffer2.hs:13:10
        ...plus 8 others
        ...plus 11 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    * In the first argument of `(==)', namely `Nada <> Nada'
      In the expression: Nada <> Nada == Nada
      In an equation for `testNadaNada':
          testNadaNada = Nada <> Nada == Nada
   |
19 | testNadaNada = Nada <> Nada == Nada
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^

src\LoadAndInteractiveDiffer2.hs:19:16: error:
    * Ambiguous type variable `a0' arising from a use of `=='
      prevents the constraint `(Eq a0)' from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `a0' should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Eq Ordering -- Defined in `GHC.Classes'
        instance Eq Integer
          -- Defined in `integer-gmp-1.0.3.0:GHC.Integer.Type'
        instance Eq a => Eq (Optional a)
          -- Defined at src\LoadAndInteractiveDiffer2.hs:8:10
        ...plus 23 others
        ...plus 17 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    * In the expression: Nada <> Nada == Nada
      In an equation for `testNadaNada':
          testNadaNada = Nada <> Nada == Nada
   |
19 | testNadaNada = Nada <> Nada == Nada
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

(Commenting out the `testNadaNada = Nada <> Nada == Nada`, of course makes the file load succesfully).
However, when I do the same thing interactively, the behavior is as expected:

```
Prelude > Nada <> Nada == Nada
True

Prelude > testNadaNada = Nada <> Nada == Nada
Prelude > testNadaNada
True
```

As said, I think the answer is indicated in [Haskell: Loading a file with a definition fails, while doing it interactively in GHCi works well. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68713776/haskell-loading-a-file-with-a-definition-fails-while-doing-it-interactively-in), but I am not able to map the original solution to my actual problem. I have tried editing the file to: `testNadaNada = Nada <> Nada == Nada :: Optional Integer` to parallell the original solution, but to no success. Any help?

Comment: It's so much the identical question that I would vote to close as a duplicate, were it not your own question that you've specifically referred to. Surely you can see that your `Optional a` is completely equivalent ("isomorphic" as mathematicians, and many Haskellers, would say) to `Maybe a`, with `Nada` playing the role of `Nothing`? So the answer will be exactly the same.

Comment: As for the last sentence - clearly `Nada <> Nada == Nada` is of type `Bool`, so this is a type error. It's `Nada` that you want to annotate as `Optional Integer` (for example)

Comment: note the parentheses in the answer you were given there: `testNothingIsNothing = Nothing == (Nothing :: Maybe Integer)`. That's what you're missing

Comment: Editing the file to ```testNadaNada :: Bool
testNadaNada = (Nada <> Nada) == (Nada :: Optional Integer)``` does not alliviate the problem.

Comment: I did not get "...so this is a type error..:". How? I want the test to return True or False. Nothing wrong with that, is it?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that in itself, but there is when you tell GHC that boolean value has to be of type `Optional Integer`

Comment: "Editing the file to `testNadaNada :: Bool testNadaNada = (Nada <> Nada) == (Nada :: Optional Integer)` does not alliviate [sic] the problem" -- yes it does. It just reveals that there is also a *second* problem.

Comment: Which is? I think maybe the problem is in Integer not being a Monoid by itself. But I have not succeeded in formulating the constraint. I have tried variants of Sum/Product just to investigate, but I do not see the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
testNadaNada = Nada <> Nada == Nada
```

...
qualify Nada as an Optional of a Semigroup, e.g. Sum a

```
testNadaNada :: Bool
testNadaNada = (Nada <> Nada) == (Nada  :: Optional (Sum Int))
```

The answer implicitly lay in your answers, but I could not figure out the details and syntax. After some fiddling, I got it, thanks for your guidance!